# on Upgrading to gradle plugin 3.2.0, getting error "Cannot fit requested classes in the main-dex file"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to upgrade my android project gradle version from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0 and getting errors about DexArchiveMergerException , while reverting back make its working fine.

I'm using android studio 3.3.2, when i first changed gradle version to 3.2.0, its start giving error about kotlin databinding which i resolved
by removing this line from my app dependencies

`kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0`

but now I'm getting this error

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:90)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:115)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Cannot fit requested classes in the main-dex file (# methods: 143948 > 65536 ; # fields: 73772 > 65536)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile.throwIfFull(VirtualFile.java:192)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile$DistributorBase.fillForMainDexList(VirtualFile.java:317)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile$FillFilesDistributor.run(VirtualFile.java:369)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.distribute(ApplicationWriter.java:178)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.write(ApplicationWriter.java:199)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:179)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.lambda$run$1(D8.java:93)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:55)
    ... 10 more
```

while in my defaultConfig in my app build.gradle i already included

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

as also my minSDk = 19, therefore i also included depependency :

```
implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"
```

if I just revert the gradle version to 3.1.0, everything works fine. Need some help here, if there is any bug with gradle 3.2.0 ??

Comment: what is your distribution URL?  in gradle-wrapper.properties  file. Also, check this link to understand different versions  https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: @DiptenduDas `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip` I already fixed that part while upgrading.

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: done it many times, but still no luck.